# I am not able to select a default value for dropdown using angular filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add default value to ng-option but I am not able to do so.
Here is my code

```
var app = angular.module('jobs',[]).constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:8000/');

app.controller('jobsController', function($scope, $http, API_URL, $timeout){
    $scope.selectedItem = "Years";
    console.log("hihi");
});

angular.module('jobs').filter("minmax", function(){
    return function(arr, min, max){
        min = parseInt(min);
        max = parseInt(max);
        for(var i =min; i <= max; i++){
            arr.push(i);
        }
        return arr;
    };
});


<div class="m-banner-1" ng-controller="jobsController">
    <select class="ui fluid normal dropdown" data-ng-model="selectedItem"
             ng-options="opt as opt for opt in [] | minmax:0:30">
    </select>
</div>
```

Here's [a link](https://plnkr.co/edit/OFJa1AaGcdxBPc4WElBz?p=preview)!

I want "Years" selected as default

Please help

Comment: That makes no sense. Your array of options contains numbers. "Years" is not a number, and is not any of the options, so it can't be selected. And even then, if you want $scope.selectedItem to be the selection, ng-model should be `ng-model="selectedItem"`. Not `ng-model="proofGroupId"`. What do you actually want? Do you want a select box showing numbers, with a default option at the top showing "Years"?

Comment: Yes exactly I want a select box showing numbers, with a default option at the top showing "Years"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, your array of options contains numbers. "Years" is not a number, and is not any of the options, so it can't be selected. And even then, if you want `$scope.selectedItem` to be the selection, ng-model should be `ng-model="selectedItem"`. Not `ng-model="proofGroupId"`

To display a "default option", [the correct way to do](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) it is to add an option without value, and the label you want, in the HTML.

Using a filter that recreates and repopulates a new array at each digest is also not a good idea at all, and just makes things more complex and less efficient than they should be. That's not what filters are for.

Here's how it should look like:

```
var app = angular.module('jobs',[]);

app.controller('jobsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.opts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    $scope.opts.push(i);
  }
});

<div class="m-banner-1" ng-controller="jobsController">

  <select class="ui fluid normal dropdown" ng-model="proofGroupId"
          ng-options="opt as opt for opt in opts">
    <option value="">Years</option>
  </select>

  {{ proofGroupId }}
</div>
```

And here it is [in a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qkb0Ig7jl5KnkPJF7LvR?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestion.This is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add empty default option manually:

```
<select class="ui fluid normal dropdown" 
  ng-model="selectedItem"
  ng-options="opt as opt for opt in [] | minmax:0:30">
  <option value="">Years</option>
</select>
```